# Lists and matrix using sapply

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe, sapply

I have a perhaps basic questions and I have searched on the web. I have a problem reading files. Though, I managed to get to read my files, following @Konrad suggestions, which I appreciate: How to get R to read in files from multiple subdirectories under one large directory?

It is a similar problem, however, I have not resolved it.

My problem:

I have large number of files of with same name ("tempo.out") in different folders. This tempo.out has 5 columns/headers. And they are all the same format with 1048 lines and 5 columns:

id X Y time temp

```
setwd("~/Documents/ewat")
dat.files  <- list.files(path="./ress",
                 recursive=T,
                 pattern="tempo.out"
                 ,full.names=T)
readDatFile <- function(f) {
dat.fl <- read.table(f)  
 }

data.filesf <- sapply(dat.files, readDatFile)                         

# I might not have the right sintax in sub5:
subs5 <- sapply(data.filesf,`[`,5) 
matr5 <- do.call(rbind, subs5)   

probs <- c(0.05,0.1,0.16,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.84,0.90,0.95,0.99)
q <- rowQuantiles(matr5, probs=probs)
print(q)
```

I want to extract the fifth column (temp) of each of those thousands of files and make calculations such as quantiles.

I tried first to read all subfiles in "ress"

The latter gave no error, but my main problem is the "data.filesf" is not a matrix but list, and actually the 5th column is not what I expected. Then the following:

```
matr5 <- do.call(rbind, subs5)
```

is also not giving the required values/results.

What could be the best way to get columns into what will become a huge matrix?

Comment: Up front: I suggest either you do `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)` or you use `lapply`, otherwise this is a little fragile. For instance, if you pass it a vector of 2+ filenames, it should return a *`list`*, in which case you access each one with `data.filesf[[1]]` notation; however, if by bad luck your list of filenames is only one long, then `sapply` (no `simplify=FALSE`) will return a single matrix or data.frame, and `data.filesf[[1]]` will notably not do what you expect.

Comment: I've confused myself into a circle ... pls give some sample input (e.g., a dummy 3x3 data.frame repeated twice) and the intended output.

Answer (score 0):

Try
     lapply(data.filef,`[`,,5)
Hope this will help

Comment: When only passed a single argument (like `DF[5]`), a `data.frame` will return another `data.frame` with that column.

Comment: @Nathan. Am sorry I did not quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Please add a comma after the object. Try `lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars),'[', , 5)`. There must be a comma after the object. You forgot to put it. Thank you

Comment: @r2evans The statement is **"I want to extract the fifth column (temp) of each of those thousands of files and make calculations such as quantiles"** That is the statement he wrote

Comment: Regardless, the OP also stated: *"main problem is the "data.filesf" is not a matrix but **list**"* (emphasis mine), which your answer does not change, and then *"5th column is not what I expected"*, suggesting that nobody really knows which between column or row is truly the intent. (And your statement that *"you are actually extracting the 5th row"* is incorrect.)

Comment: ~data.filesf~ itself is a list. What does it contain? Dataframes?Maybe I did not read the question. I will reread again

Comment: hello @Parfait. I have used the code perfectly, until yesterday that started giving the following error:  Error in read.table(f, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  no lines available in input  If I change to sep = " " it will give error more columns than columns names. I have tried to modify with strip.white. It is definatelya  problem with separator, but nothings has worked (and are similar files as when I posted this months ago). THank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider extending your defined function, *readDatFile*, to extract fifth column, *temp*, and assign directly to matrix with `sapply` or `vapply` (since you know ahead the needed structure -numeric matrix length equal to nrows or 1048). Then, run needed `rowQuantiles`:

```
setwd("~/Documents/ewat")

dat.files  <- list.files(path="./ress",
                         recursive=T,
                         pattern="tempo.out",
                         full.names=T)

readDatFile <- function(f) read.table(f)$temp  # OR USE read.csv(f)[[5]]

matr5 <- sapply(dat.files, readDatFile, USE.NAMES=FALSE)                         
# matr5 <- vapply(dat.files, readDatFile, numeric(1048), USE.NAMES=FALSE)

probs <- c(0.05,0.1,0.16,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.84,0.90,0.95,0.99)
q <- rowQuantiles(matr5, probs=probs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Parfait (and all) for explanations and help. Adding the $temp  retrieved the needed values.